# How to shut down X?

Tags: xorg

What if I'd like to exit the X session to use raw console without any X process running?
I know I can always press Ctrl+Alt+F1/F6 to switch between a raw console and a graphical environment, but some times I just want the last to be gone (for technical reasons). So how to shut it down correctly, preventing from being automatically respawned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To Stop X.Org Server:**

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

**To Start X.Org Server:**

```
startx

##(OR)

sudo service lightdm start
```

**To Restart X.Org Server:**

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

In all cases, replace `lightdm` with whatever greeter/display manager you use. `lightdm` is Ubuntu's default display manager.

Comment: Yes, I know you asked about how to stop it alone, but posting to start and restart the service in a single place might help others :)

Comment: Technically, you're stopping the desktop environment GNOME, which then shutdowns Xorg. Replace `gdm` by `kdm`, `xdm`, `ldm` or whatever desktop environment you're using.

Comment: `lightdm` in my case :-)

Answer (score 2):

On my ubuntu18, the command to stop X was:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type sudo service lightdm stop, it replies lightdm stop/status: This is a clue.

```
sudo lightdm stop
```

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 14.04 from a virtual terminal Ctrl-Alt-f1-6. You will probably have to hit Ctrl-C afterwords to get back to a command prompt.